# A working example of mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I tried to make the basic examples of `mdframed` given in the corresponding documentation, but I get an error stating

```
! You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.
```

The example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\global\mdfapptodefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
rightline=true,innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10,
frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulecolor=green,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,
frametitlerulewidth=2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,frametitle={Inhomogeneous linear}]
\ExampleText
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: I do not see the `\ExampleText` being defined in your example. Erase that and insert a sample text, for example, use the `lipsum` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code:

- You are using `\mdfapptodefinestyle`. But the style `exampledefault` isn't defined here. So the command fails. To define a style use `\mdfdefinestyle`.
- The command `\ExampleText` is defined in my example files but not in your example. So run:

Here are some comments copied from the example file:

- Every `\global` inside the examples is necessary to work with the
  package `showexpl`.
- All examples have the following settings:

  ```
  \mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
  \newrobustcmd\ExampleText{%
      An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation
      has the form
      \begin{align}
          L[v ] = f,
      \end{align}
      where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is
      the dependent variable, and $f$ is a given non−zero
      function of the independent variables alone.
  }
  ```

Here an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
rightline=true,innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10,
frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulecolor=green,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,
frametitlerulewidth=2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,frametitle={Inhomogeneous linear}]
Some Text
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```